Name of mini potentiometer type?
I’m doing a repair of a compressor, but can’t find the potentiometers I need. I seems like a miniature version of the classic size that normally has 5 mm, and instead everything about 20% smaller. The pin spacing is 4mm, and they’re 12mm wide. Classic style with 3 pins 1 gang 1 turn. Is there a name for this size of potentiometer?

I don't know what a "classic size" potentiometer is, and I assume 5mm describes the body length? Or the shaft diameter? Either way, a 20% smaller potentiometer would still be a potentiometer, I'd say; you'll probably have to scour the inventory of one of the large distributors (mouser.com, digikey.com, farnell.com…) to find what you're looking for.

OP means that the three pins are commonly on a 5 mm pitch but these are on 4 mm pitch. I have no idea what "they're 12 mm wide" means. To the OP: provide photos, state what equipment brand and model you are repairing and likely country of design / manufacture as that will give a clue. (e.g., Compressor could be an air compressor or an audio signal compressor. It may be obvious to you but it's not to us.)

Assuming you're comparing with typical panel-mount (and not some other kind) of potentiometer with a 6mm or 1/4" shaft, I would start by searching for the outer  diameter of the case.
For example, searching for 12mm potentiometer (assuming a hard metric dimension). Or 13mm potentiometer. Both yield useful-looking hits. There are smaller parts with 1/8" or 3mm shafts.
If it's a hard Imperial device you might also try looking for the closest fractional inch or decimal inch dimension, but I'd start with metric anyway.
For example, here is a Foshan Song Huei pot with pin spacing of 7.5mm/2  = 3.75mm, pretty close to what you measured.

You could try searching for Chinese part numbers which tend to be similar or the same for different manufacturers, even if the specs vary slightly.

This is good info, can’t find any domestically though, I did however find these alphas too, but again nowhere I can just buy 5 of each kind I need. http://www.alphapotentiometers.net/html/12mm_pot_9.html

You might have to compromise on shaft and termination style to find something in low quantity. In practice these things are frequently ordered in quantity direct from the manufacturer, such as Alpha, exactly as the manufacturer wants them. If you are willing to saw off the shaft, adapt to different terminations or change the knob style you have a much better chance. But shopping questions are off topic here. I don't think 'how to shop' is off topic exactly, but neither is it encouraged IME.
